# Styling individual routes with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Hi so I'm in a predicament where I'm trying to make elements on a specific route wider, but because of the overall styling I have for all routes I'm unable to do this. If anyone could point me in the correct direction that would be great.

I'm trying to make the Admin component appear wider, but the maxWidth constraint is not allowing me to do so. How would I be able to apply the maxWidth constraint to all other elements except the Admin component?

Here is the following code snippet I'm working with:

```
<Container className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style={{ minHeight: "85vh" }}>
        <div className="w-100" style={{ maxWidth: "400px" }}>
          <Router>
            <Navigation />
            <AuthProvider>
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path="/" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                      <Route exact path="/" element={<Dashboard />}/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/update-profile" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                      <Route exact path="/update-profile" element={<UpdateProfile />}/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/admin"  element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                      <Route exact path="/admin" element={<Admin />}/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                    <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
                </Routes>
            </AuthProvider>
          </Router>
        </div>
      </Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround inspired from a previous project of mine:

1. Modify `<PrivateRoute/>` component to also check the navigated route and wrap the returned element with a div that has appropriate styling.

This is what your `<PrivateRoute/>` component may look like now:

---

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
    // Your auth provider should produce this value.
    let isAuthenticated = true; 

    const location = useLocation();

    if (!isAuthenticated) {
        // Optionally pass attempted route as state.
        return <Navigate to="/login" 
                         state={{ from: location.pathname }} 
                         replace={true} />;
    }

    const width = location.pathname === "/admin" ? "800px" : "400px";

    return (
        <div style={{ width: width, border: "2px solid red" }}>
            <Routes>{children}</Routes>
        </div>
    );
}
```

2. Create a `<PublicRoute/>` component to wrap unprotected routes and do similar:

---

```
const PublicRoute = ({ children }) => {
  return (
      <div style={{ width: "400px", border: "2px solid black" }}>
          <Routes>{children}</Routes>
      </div>
  );
}
```

3. Remove the inner `<div>` within the `<Container>`.
4. Within the `<Routes>` nesting, pass the *public* and *private* route components from earlier as elements that wrap the routes:

Here's the rest of the code now:

---

```
// `*` is used in paths for infinite deep matching.

<Container
    className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" 
    style={{ minHeight: "85vh" }}>
    <Router>
      <Navigation /> 

      // Private routes
      <Routes> 
        <Route 
          path="/*"
          element={
            // PrivateRoute should wrap the route.
            <PrivateRoute location="/">
              <Route exact path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
            </PrivateRoute>
          }
        />
        <Route 
          path="/update-profile/*"
          element={
            <PrivateRoute location="/">
              <Route exact path="/" element={<UpdateProfile />} />
            </PrivateRoute>
          }
        />
        <Route 
          path="/admin/*"
          element={
            <PrivateRoute location="/">
              <Route exact path="/" element={<Admin />} />
            </PrivateRoute>
          } 
        />

        // Public routes
        <Route
          path="/signup/*"
          element={
            <PublicRoute location="/">
              <Route exact path="/" element={<Signup />} />
            </PublicRoute>
          }/>
        <Route
          path="/login/*"
          element={
            <PublicRoute location="/">
              <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
            </PublicRoute>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/forgot-password/*"
          element={
            <PublicRoute location="/">
              <Route exact path="/" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
            </PublicRoute>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
</Container>
```